# web site style is off center in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been spinning my head for 2 days trying to find out why my site looks so messy in IE8, and 9. It looks fine in Chrome and Firefox. I need help, I can't find the CSS issue...

http://tytonsound.com/ is the web site.

In IE, there's some scripts that aren't being noticed. (Like the nav bar). In addition, the nav bar is off center, and shifts down a little.

Please let me know if you notice anything that would be causing the site to be off center.

Comment: omg, that did it. post that as an answer for your points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a doctype which is causing IE to render your site in [Quirks Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode).

If you're using any HTML5 you should place `<!doctype html>` at the top of your file (make sure nothing precedes this, not even white space) otherwise use an XHTML or HTML 4 doctype.

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking `!DOCTYPE` element before your html tag (IE is very picky about this)

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#dtds

Look through the different types for xhtml and decide which fits your needs.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html ...>
    ...
```